# How to delete the button if got click in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How to delete the button in tkinter if it got click then play the function example this is the code

```
from tkinter import *
s = Tk()
#example this the game
def game():
    pass


#if this button got click this button should be gone and play the game
b = Button(s,text="play",command=game)


b.grid(row=1)

s.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method your looking for

```
b.destroy()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: It is just a single line of code and its pretty self explanatory as it just destroys the element

Comment: It's not self explanatory because you haven't described or shown how to use and also call `game()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [`grid_remove()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/grid-methods.html) method as part of what is executed when the `Button` is clicked.

```
from tkinter import *

s = Tk()

def game():
    print('game running')

b = Button(s, text="play",
           command=lambda: (b.grid_remove(), game()))  # Hide button and call game.
b.grid(row=1)

s.mainloop()
```